# Sometimes my apps crashes with android.view.InflateException after target to API 28

Tags: android

After target my apps to api 28, Fabric shows me some crashes that said:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mydomain.myapp/com.mydomain.myapp.SplashScreen}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class <unknown>
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2330)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2392)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:156)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5278)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)

Caused by android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class <unknown>
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
   at base.activity.BaseSplash.onCreate(BaseSplash.java:149)
   at com.mydomain.myapp.SplashScreen.onCreate(SplashScreen.java:77)
```

In all kinds of devices and in the splash screen but only on less than 0.1% of the users. Before target to API 28 I did not have this error.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bckgrnd_splash">

<View
    android:id="@+id/grass"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:background="@color/grass"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

<View
    android:background="@drawable/grass"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:id="@+id/grassImage"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<View
    android:background="@drawable/road_bckgrnd"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:id="@+id/roadView"
    android:layout_above="@+id/grass"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<View
    android:background="@color/grassRoad"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:id="@+id/topRoadView"
    android:layout_above="@+id/roadView"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/buildins"
    android:background="@drawable/buildings_cloud"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="138dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/topRoadView"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<ImageView
    android:paddingTop="20dp"
    android:src="@drawable/splash_bus_sitp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/grassImage"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
    android:id="@+id/sitpImage" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/taxiImage"
    android:src="@drawable/splash_taxi"
    android:layout_above="@id/grass"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/tmImage"
    android:src="@drawable/splash_bus_tm"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/grassImage"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/cloudLeft"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:src="@drawable/splash_cloud_left"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/logo"
    android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/cloudLeft"
    android:src="@drawable/splash_logo"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/logo"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:src="@drawable/splash_cloud_right"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Someone can help me with this issue? or maybe know something about that? Line #14 is the second view.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Could you please share the layout which is being inflated and also the onCreateView method where it is inflated?

Comment: I did not see anything estrange on the layout. In fact 99.9% of the sessions works fine. The error is only with 0.1% of the sessions.

Comment: looks like one of your image migh be corrupted. if its your second view check your `@drawable/grass`

Comment: But is strange. Only happens on 0.01% of the sessions.